# Peer-2-peer or client/server connection over cell network to connect 2 android device

Tags: java, android

I want make an android app which connects 2 android phones over cellphone network. Sort of like a chat app. I am very new to android. Here is an visual of what i need-

```
AndroidPhone1--------->send request(message saying yes/no) to connect over cellphone network------>AndroidPhone2

AndroidPhone2 accepts

AndroidPhone1<--------->connection over cellphone network<------>AndroidPhone2
```

or

```
AndroidPhone1---->send request to connect over cellphone network------>Server

Server -----> send request------AndroidPhone2

AndroidPhone2 accepts

AndroidPhone1<--------->Server<-------->AndroidPhone2
```

I researched a little and heard xmpp but not clear to me. Any pointer to start such as socket,AWS or anything is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you can use the newly announced service called [AWS AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) along with DynamoDB. AppSync supports subscribers through web sockets, which allows full duplex communication and push of messages from both client->server and server->client.

1. Request for AppSync preview from your AWS account. Request form [link](https://pages.awscloud.com/awsappsyncpreview.html).
2. Create the schemas in AppSync using GraphQL.
3. Create the storage and other connections.(Depending on your use case, you can go from two tier to three tier backend. e.g if you have further processing and rules to be applied, you can go for API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB and Stream from there to AppSync, or for simple use case, you can directly push messages to DynamoDB given that you have temporal access tokens with fine-grained access control to DynamoDB. Note: Here you can use AWS Cognito to get those tokens also supporting the authentication)
4. Write a mobile app subscribing with App Sync and Pushing messages to the backend.

There are two more options you can consider.

- Using Cognito Sync.
- Using the previously mentioned stack without AppSync but with AWS IOT Websockets.